# Programmatically make a multi-line label

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I need to programmatically make some labels and text fields. I can get there.

```
    //create the file name label
    NSTextField* newFileNameLabel = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(objXPos, objYPos, 300.0, 20.0)];
    //set properties
    [newFileNameLabel setBordered: NO];
    [newFileNameLabel setTextColor: [NSColor whiteColor]];
    [newFileNameLabel setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [newFileNameLabel setEditable:NO];
    [newFileNameLabel setStringValue: @"File Name:"];

    [vSheetView addSubview:newFileNameLabel];
```

But I couldn't find anything in the docs that would let me set a wrap property. In IB the property is layout with 'scroll, wrap and truncate' as its options. NSTextField doesn't have a method to set this, and if I go up the inheritance chain neither does NSControl. NSView has a setNeedsLayout method but it doesn't seem related:

```
You only ever need to invoke this method if your view implements custom layout 
not expressible in the constraint-based layout system by overriding the layout method. 
The system invokes this method automatically for all views using constraints for layout.
```

NSTextFieldCell doesn't have any methods either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

In OS X 10.11 and Swift 2.1 the following helped me:

```
multilineLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
multilineLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(250, forOrientation: .Horizontal)
```

Setting the compression resistance is required if you use AutoLayout.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
textField.usesSingleLineMode = false
textField.cell?.wraps = true
textField.cell?.scrollable = false
```

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but `setWraps:` of `NSTextFieldCell` (inherited from `NSCell`) should do what you are after.

To get the cell, send the `cell` method to the text field. `NSTextField` inherits the `cell` method from `NSControl`, so if you want to read the docs, you need to search the docs for `NSControl`.

More about how cells work in the [NSCell docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html).

Comment: Thanks, but there's no setWraps method on the developer page and it throws an warning when I build: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextFieldCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTextFieldCell  it also looks like a NSTextField will, by default, wrap based on width and height you initially provide it.

Comment: so do I have to reference the NSTextFieldCell itself? And if so, how do I do that?