# Why SwiftUI multiline wrapping Text in macOS works in Preview, but not in real app?

Tags: macos, swiftui, nstextfield

I have a SwiftUI view which shows image and text.

```swift
import SwiftUI
#if canImport(UIKit)
typealias AppColor = UIColor
#else
typealias AppColor = NSColor
#endif

struct ReportErrorUI: View {

   enum Order {
      case even, odd
   }

   let error: String
   let order: Order

   init(error: String, order: Order) {
      self.error = error
      self.order = order
   }

   var body: some SwiftUI.View {

      let bgColor = (order == .even ? AppColor.systemGreen : .systemRed).withAlphaComponent(0.5)

      return VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
         HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8, content: {
            Image("icon.error")
            Text(error).font(.body)
         }).padding(8)
         Color(.magenta).frame(height: 2)
      }).background(Color(bgColor))
   }
}
```

Now I can preview it:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
struct ReportErrorUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {

   static let shortText = "Etiam habebis sem dicantur magna mollis euismod."
   static let longText = "Tityre, tu patulae recubans sub tegmine fagi  dolor. Idque Caesaris facere voluntate liceret: sese habere. Unam incolunt Belgae, aliam Aquitani, tertiam."

   static var previews: some SwiftUI.View {
      Group {
         VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ReportErrorUI(error: longText, order: .even)
            ReportErrorUI(error: shortText, order: .odd)
         }.previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
         .background(Color.white).padding().frame(width: 320)
      }
   }
}
```

Here is it looks like:

As you can see the `Text` view works as expected – long text is wrapped.

[image: Swift UI Preview]

Now I am adding this `ReportErrorUI` alongside with old-school `NSTextField` multiline label, into existing AppKit application via `NSHostingController` or `NSHostingView`. Both UI elements added into `NSStackView`.

```swift
class MainViewController: ReusableViewController {

   private lazy var stackView = NSStackView()

   override func setupUI() {
      view.addSubview(stackView)
      stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
      stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
      stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
      stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true

      stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 120).isActive = true
      stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 80).isActive = true

      stackView.orientation = .vertical
      stackView.spacing = 8
      stackView.distribution = .fill
      stackView.alignment = .leading

      // Wrappable multiline label. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920653/1418981
      let label = NSTextField()
      label.stringValue = "Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident culpa. A communi observantia non est recedendum."
      label.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(1), for: .horizontal)
      label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(1), for: .horizontal)
      label.isEditable = false
      label.backgroundColor = NSColor.magenta.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
      label.isBezeled = false
      label.isSelectable = true
      //> Below 4 lines seems not needed.
      // label.usesSingleLineMode = false
      // label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
      // label.cell?.wraps = true
      // label.cell?.isScrollable = false
      //<
      stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

      do {
         let ui = ReportErrorUI(error: "Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident culpa. A communi observantia non est recedendum.", order: .even)
         let view = NSHostingView(rootView: ui)
         view.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(1), for: .horizontal)
         view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(1), for: .horizontal)
         view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
         stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
      }

      do {
         let ui = ReportErrorUI(error: "Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident culpa. A communi observantia non est recedendum.", order: .odd)
         let vc = NSHostingController(rootView: ui)
         addChild(vc)
         vc.view.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(1), for: .horizontal)
         vc.view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(1), for: .horizontal)
         vc.view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
         stackView.addArrangedSubview(vc.view)
      }

      do {
         let view = ReusableView()
         view.backgroundColor = .yellow
         view.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 12).isActive = true
         stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
      }

   }
}
```

As result old-school `NSTextField` works as expected - multiline text wraps itself on Application window resize. But text inside SwiftUI `Text` view is not wrapped.

[image: Real App]

Tricks from UIKit world, like `lineLimit(nil)` or `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`, either not working or breaking Application window layout.

Here for instance how `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` works - Application window layout is broken. Application window cannot be vertically resized.

[image: Broken layout]

Any combination of `setContentCompressionResistancePriority` or `setContentHuggingPriority` for `horizontal`, `vertical` axes set on `NSHostingView` or `NSHostingController` not helping.

How to make multiline wrapping SwiftUI `Text` working correctly on macOS?

Answer (score 3):

The solution for macOS.

Thanks to this article: https://zalogatomek.medium.com/swiftui-missing-intrinsic-content-size-how-to-get-it-6eca8178a71f

```swift
struct IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
   static let defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

   static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
      value = nextValue()
   }
}

extension View {
   func readIntrinsicContentSize(to size: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
      background(GeometryReader { proxy in
         Color.clear.preference(
            key: IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey.self,
            value: proxy.size
         )
      })
      .onPreferenceChange(IntrinsicContentSizePreferenceKey.self) {
         size.wrappedValue = $0
      }
   }
}

struct MultilineText: View {

   @State private var textSize: CGSize = .zero
   let text: String

   init(_ text: String) {
      self.text = text
   }

   var body: some SwiftUI.View {
      Text(text).readIntrinsicContentSize(to: $textSize).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true).frame(height: textSize.height)
   }
}
```